# Button Not Adding Up

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def login_button():
    wrong_value_count = 0
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    if username == user1_username and password == user1_password:
        redirecting_text = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Credentials Match, Please Wait While " 
        "We Redirect You To Your Vault", fill="red", anchor=NW)
        canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text(redirecting_text))
        print("ESHTA")
    elif username == user2_username and password == user2_password:
        redirecting_text2 = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Credentials Match, Please Wait While " 
        "We Redirect You To Your Vault", fill="red", anchor=NW)
        canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text3(redirecting_text2))
        print("ESHTA")
    else:
        wrong_value_count += 1
        if wrong_value_count <= 3:
            print("NOT ESHTA")
            wrong_credentials_text = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Wrong Credentials, Try again",
             fill="red", anchor=NW)
            canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text2(wrong_credentials_text))
        elif wrong_value_count > 3:
            lock_text = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Sorry, You've Reached the Max Number of Trials"
            " Please Try Again Later", fill="red", anchor=NW)
            canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text4(lock_text))
        print(wrong_value_count)
```

Alright, so I'm trying to add to the wrong value count, but every time I click the button, it shows that it's still 1. How do make it add up till it reaches 3 as written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wrong_value_count` must be outside the button because when `login_button` is called it resets the count to 0, which you don't want.

```py
wrong_value_count = 0
def login_button():
    global wrong_value_count 
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    if username == user1_username and password == user1_password:
        redirecting_text = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Credentials Match, Please Wait While " 
        "We Redirect You To Your Vault", fill="red", anchor=NW)
        canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text(redirecting_text))
        print("ESHTA")
    elif username == user2_username and password == user2_password:
        redirecting_text2 = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Credentials Match, Please Wait While " 
        "We Redirect You To Your Vault", fill="red", anchor=NW)
        canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text3(redirecting_text2))
        print("ESHTA")
    else:
        wrong_value_count += 1
        if wrong_value_count <= 3:
            print("NOT ESHTA")
            wrong_credentials_text = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Wrong Credentials, Try again",
             fill="red", anchor=NW)
            canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text2(wrong_credentials_text))
        elif wrong_value_count > 3:
            lock_text = canvas.create_text(40, 90, text="Sorry, You've Reached the Max Number of Trials"
            " Please Try Again Later", fill="red", anchor=NW)
            canvas.after(2500, lambda: delete_text4(lock_text))
        print(wrong_value_count)
```

Comment: It worked, but I don't understand why?

Comment: @MarkGeorge It works because wrong_value_count  must be set to 0 when the program starts, everytime the login_button is run it does wrong_value_count += 1. The global is to import the wrong_value_count  to be access by the function. Try reading up on [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) it might help.

Comment: Thank You, Got It

Answer (score 0):

wrong_value_count += 1 need to be outside the login button. Other wise it will be set to 0